How to remove a PHP array from larger array if specific value matches a value from a separate array?
I have an array called $roster with about 16 smaller arrays in it, like this below (only showing 4 for brevity):
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [playerid] => 1055
            [firstname] => Christian
            [lastname] => McCaffrey
            [age] => 27
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [playerid] => 1362
            [firstname] => A.J.
            [lastname] => Brown
            [age] => 26
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [playerid] => 1897
            [firstname] => Joe
            [lastname] => Burrow
            [age] => 27
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [playerid] => 2019
            [firstname] => De'Von
            [lastname] => Achane
            [age] => 22
        )
)

I also have this separate array called $notneeded that only has playerids in it, like this:
Array
(
    [0] => 1055
    [1] => 1495
    [2] => 1497
    [3] => 1897
    [4] => 1775
)

I would like to loop thru the array above and if any of those 5 playerids match a playerid in the larger array, I want to remove the entire record.
For example, since 1055 and 1897 are in the smaller array above, I would like the resulting array to only have 2 players left in it (since all of McCaffrey and Burrow's info should be removed).
I tried this code below, but nothing is happening (i.e. nothing gets removed from $roster)
foreach ($notneeded as $item) {
    // Search values and remove them from $roster
    if(($key = array_search($item, $roster)) !== false) {
        unset($roster[$key]);
    }
}

Obviously I'm not good with arrays as this seems like it should be somewhat easy.  Please let me know what I'm doing wrong/stupid :)

Implementation of the advice on the exact duplicate target page: https://3v4l.org/HvkJs

Problem
Your code will only unset/remove an element from the $roster array if ($key = array_search($item, $roster)) is evaluated to something different from false.
However, the array_search function here searches for an id in the $roster array, which is an array of arrays, and it doesn't look recursively in the subarrays. Therefore, in your case, it will always return false, and never unset any element.
Solution
You can use the array_filter function in PHP.
From documentation:

array_filter(array $array, ?callable $callback = null, int $mode = 0): 

Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from array is returned into the result array.

In your case, you can use:
$roster = array_filter($roster, function($element) use ($notneeded) {
    return !in_array($element["playerid"], $notneeded);
});


$element is an array here, so you want in_array($element['playerid'], $notneeded);

Also, OP wants to remove the elements that match, not keep them, so you'll need to invert the match: !in_array($element['playerid'], $notneeded);

@AlexHowansky Thanks, I thought about both these things before typing out my answer, but then forgot about them.

Also, this question already has an exact duplicate.
